# How to compute the vertices of a hypercube given in H-form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polytopes

I am working with a hypercube given in H-form: {x: Vx <= 1}. How would I compute the vertices of this hypercube?

Answer (score 0):

An $n$-dimensional hypercube has $2n$ boundary facets and $2^n$ vertices. Thus if you have $h = |\{x: Vx <= 1\}|$ boundary equations, the searched for vertex count is just $v = 2^{h/2}$.

--- rk